# Хром перестал показывать размеры страницы

Tags: веб-программирование, webbrowser, google-chrome

Браузер Google Chrome перестал показывать размеры страницы в режиме Web Inspector (кнопка F12 или CTRL+SHIFT+I). Раньше в правом верхнем углу страницы отображались ширина и высота, а теперь не показывает. Проверял на нескольких компах, такое не только у меня. Как вернуть ширину и высоту?

Comment: Вернули! Наконец-то! А то вообще без этой фичи трудно было!

Answer (score 2):

Зайдите в `DevTools` и нажмите `F1`, далее в секции Element поставте галочку на `Show rulers`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это немного не то. Линейка показывает размеры элементов, а не окна, и только при наведении на них, а не постоянно.

Comment: Да действительно popup пропал и настройки, чтоб вернуть я не вижу. Как вариант, написать свое решение, либо довольствоваться наведением мыши на элемент

Answer (score 0):

Да, жаль убрали удобную штуку.
Я теперь перехожу в режим device (ctrl+shift+M)
Там можно тягать маленькое окошко для изменения размеров. Или задавать четко какой нужен.

Answer (score 0):

обязательно нажмите на это кнопку на панели и размер будет отображаться[image: введите сюда описание изображения]